# Disable individual autocompletes in Atom

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

I'm using Github's Atom and while writing go, I get this:

[image]

which autocompletes to:

```
package func main() {

}
```

which is not legal Go.

I can just press space or undo it after it gets autocompleted, but is it possible to disable individual autocompletes in Atom's Autocompletion engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autocomplete as you have described is in called [Snippets](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/) in GitHub's Atom parlance.  At the time of writing, disabling snippets introduced by either core or community packages is not supported, there is however a [enhancement ticket](https://github.com/atom/snippets/issues/55) to provide support in the [Snippets package](https://github.com/atom/snippets).

As an alternative you could follow the instructions in the Atom Flight Manual to override the `main` snippet with a snippet that was either valid Go, something that might not be possible or simply a snippet that replaces the word `main` with `main`, simply add the following to your personal `snippets.cson` which can be accessed from `File` -> `Snippets...`:

```coffee
'.source.go':
  'Main':
    'prefix': 'main'
    'body': 'main'
```

At best it's a hack but it does prevent the main Snippet from expanding when you don't want it to.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is going to be really useful in the future :D